# Restrict email recipients based on email keyword in MS Outlook 2010

Tags: email, outlook, keyword, restrict, validationrules

I work in a medical study where study coordinators at several off-site locations will be sending sensitive data via email attachments.  These emails will be encrypted, but I cannot have the emails going to anyone but one or two specific recipients.  I need a method to restrict who can receive email attachments based on a keyword in the email subject line.  We are using MS Outlook 2010.

Ideally, it'd work this way: If the sender's email's subject line includes a keyword like 'RestrictedEmail' then only designated email recipients (for example, king@kong.com or robin@hood.com) can receive the email, else, the email will not send.

I didn't see this elsewhere in archives.  Maybe I'm not using the right keywords...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Trap the Application.ItemSend event, look at the message subject (Mail.Subject). If the match is found, loop through the MailItem.Recipients collection and check each Recipient.Address property to make sure only approved addresses are present.